# Can I cover the roots of my cherry tree?

Tags: trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raised bed around tree. Do I need to protect the trunk?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/raised-bed-around-tree-do-i-need-to-protect-the-trunk)

I want to put a circular bench around my cherry tree but need to make the ground level.  It's not level due to its roots. Is there anything I can do?  I was thinking about covering the area with sand and pebbles but understand this would harm the tree. I love the tree and do not want to lose it. Help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have a cherry tree that has mulch all around it - to prevent grass from growing there. It is doing fine after many years of mulch. Perhaps mulch (ground hardwood) is a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Trees like it just the way it is.  You can change the grade by small amounts and mulch is a good way to do so as it allows some air movement to the roots below.

[This answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/raised-bed-around-tree-do-i-need-to-protect-the-trunk) has more detail on the ways to change grade.  If you do not raise the grade more than a half inch to an inch a year that should work.  However, not changing anything is guaranteed to work.